# Cypress.io - problem with logging out from page

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, cypress, webstorm

There's an element on a page that I need to test with Cypress to log out from the page :

```html
<a _ngcontent-jee-c99="" class="logout ng-tns-c99-0 ng-star-inserted"> Logout </a>
```

I'm not familiar with this tool and programming, this is my fresh start.
How can I implement solution for that ?

In the same case I had to log in, but it was quiet simple due to button class for it :

```js
cy.get ('input')
    .click()
cy.get('input[type="email"]')
    .should('be.visible')
    .type('test@test.com')
cy.get('button[type="submit"]')
    .click()
cy.get('input[type="password"]')
    .should('be.visible')
    .type('password')
cy.get('button[type="submit"]')
    .click()
```

Comment: Hi Maciej. You mentioned a problem, however not assigned any output or tracelogs. To better understand the problem and provide a potential solution, please attach screenshots, logs or any output of your test ;).

Answer (score 2):

A good practice is to add test IDs to elements that you want to interact with e.g.

```
<a href="https://google.com" class="button" data-testid="logout">Logout</a>
```

Then you can do:

```
cy.get('[data-testid="logout"]').click()
```

The example you provided seems pretty messy. You could probably use something like:

```
cy.get('.logout').click()
```

but I would strongly recommend using the test IDs. You can find more information and best practices on selectors [here in the Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of selector `a` and text `Logout` to find and perform click.

```js
cy.contains('a', 'Logout').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The class shown in `class="logout` can be used.

```js
cy.get('a.logout')         // element is <a>, class to find is .logout
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```

After the logging-in click here

```js
cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click()
```

the Logout button may not show for a short period, so adding `.should('be.visible')` allows the test to wait for the button to appear.

Comment: I manage to check all your advices recently, but it always came to an error : "can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 2 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element".

Comment: Found a solution, thanks all! There was an index $0 which I needed to refer to.

    cy.get('a.logout').eq(0)
        .click({ force : true})